# listview display images from internet and data from sqlite

Tags: android, listview

My cursor gets 3 columns of data from sqlite, 1st column is recipe name, 2nd column in recipe author and 3rd column is the url for the recipe's image. here's a portion of my code

```
private static final String fields[] = { "recipeID", "recipeName", "thumbnail"};
Cursor mCursor = dbAdapter.getAllTitles(); //get all titles returns the recipe name, author and thumbs
startManagingCursor(mCursor);
dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.recipelist, mCursor, fields,    
                  new int[] { R.id.recipeAuthor, R.id.recipeName, R.id.recipeThumb });
setListAdapter(dataSource);
```

Obviously instead of displaying the recipe image, the code above just displays the url for the recipe image at R.id.recipeThumb. How can I make it display pictures from the internet instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post right below the answer in this discussion might be of use to you:

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: actually i've been looking at the lazylist post too before, but haven't got the time to modify it to suit my problem.. but I guess I should spend more time looking at it then

Answer (score 0):

You need a CustomAdapter and override the getView() method.
In the getView() method based on the Url you create a ImageView.

```
getView(...) {
   //First Create a Drawable from the InputStream of the Url 
   //store this drawable locally so that you don't have to fetch it again 
   Drawable imgDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream,"");
   //set this in the imageView
   imgView.setImageDrawable(imgDrawable);

   //set this imgView in the contentview and return

}
```